# How to refresh pivot data in Excel 2010? (= F9 in 2003)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2003 pressing F9 was refreshing the data in pivot table.

How to achieve the same in Excel 2010?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

How I figured that out:

- Hover over the button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the question come from a colleague, I never use Excel, so I asked here.